# How should I wire this sensor and board for rugged experimentation?

Tags: arduino, sensor

I want to use this Hall sensor on my bike for some experiments. At my desk, I've simply been using the quick connector and loosely connecting the wires to an Arduino featherboard to write the software and test.

I'm planning on improvising a solution to mount the featherboard and sensor on the bike. My question is, how should I wire it? I'm a total beginner at electronics engineering, so looking for tips and tricks on good ways to do it. e.g. Barring any better ideas, I'm planning on continuing to use the quick connector on the sensor side, then cutting the excess wire and soldering the wires to the appropriate connection on the board.
I'm ok with permanently connecting it, although a reusable solution would be even better.

[image]

Comment: Will there be a housing for the boards?

Comment: You are aware that the PCB name implies it is a switch and not an analogue output device. I'm mentioning this just in case.

Comment: @ocrdu that's another problem i'll have...my current thought is to eventually print a housing, and initially just start with some foam and duct tape :)

Comment: @Andyaka this PCB has both an analog and digital output. i learned the hard way by first buying a digital-only switch.

Answer (score 1):

You could sodler pins to the featherboard, and insert it into a solderless breadboard, or prototype PCB with female connectors. The sensor pins could go directly into the solderless breadboard, or into a female connector on the prototype board. (The protype board requires some soldering.

Or solder female headers to the featherboard, and plug the sensor pins directly into those.

Unfortunately, when you order these options on mechanical strength they are approximately in reverse order of flexibility.

For use on a bike I would rule out the solderless breadboard. For an experiment the other options might be OK, but soldering the wires directly is probably the only long-term reliable option.

Guessing that re-using the featherboard is probably more important that re-using the sensor, I'd go for pins on the feather, female headers on a prototype board, and solder the sensor wires directly onto the prototype board.